# Commutative ring of 2x2 matrices and showing unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $M(2, R)$ the ring of $2$ × $2$ matrices with entries from $R$. Show that $A ∈ M(2, R)$ is a unit if and only if $det(A)$ is a unit in $R$.

So, suppose that $A \in M$ and that it is a unity. Then we have that  $(A)(A^{-1}) = I = (A^{-1})(A)$ since this is a commutative ring. So this means that since $A$ is invertible, it has a determinant. I'm having trouble proceeding from this point. I was thinking maybe $det (A^{-1}) = \frac {1}{det(A)}$ and $det(A)det (A^{-1}) = 1$. Since $A$ has entries from $R$, it would follow that $det(A) \in R$. So since $det(A)det (A^{-1}) =1$, $A$ is a unity in $R$. And then I would have to prove the reverse implication of this.

Any help would be appreciated. Please note: $R \neq \Bbb R$. My instructor was explicit about this fact.

Comment: The proof that the adjugate of $A$ times $A$ is the scalar matrix having $\det A$ on the diagonal works over any commutative ring.

Comment: Actually from $\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=1$ it follows that $\det(A)$ is a unit in $R$ not that $A$ is a unit Now go the other way and show if $\det(A)$ is a unit in $R$ then $A$ is a unit in the matrix group.

Comment: Whoops sorry. I meant that $det (A)$ is a unit in $R$. Did I make any other mistakes? @coffeemath

Comment: Nid- No that was the only error. Aristide's answer below finishes the if and only if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is invertible, there exists $B$ such that $AB=I$, $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)=1$ so $det(A)$ is invertible. done.

Suppose that $det(A)$ is invertible, write $A=\pmatrix{a&c\cr b&d}$, the inverse of $A$ is ${1\over{det(A)}}\pmatrix{d &-c\cr -b&a}$ done